# TypeScriptによる２次元配列の型定義

Tags: typescript

### 概要

現在、TypeScriptを用いた開発を行っていますが、２次元配列の型定義で詰まってしまいました。
具体的には、下記の様な配列をTypeScriptで型定義するのに詰まっています。

```
const clapped_items[
  2: [
    {
        "user_id": 0,
        "clapped_num": 15
    },
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "clapped_num": 3
    },
  ],
  5: [
    {
        "user_id": 3,
        "clapped_num": 15
    },
    {
        "user_id": 2,
        "clapped_num": 3
    },
    {
        "user_id": 4,
        "clapped_num": 11
    },
  ]
];
```

自分では下記の様に型定義しましたが、この方法ではエラーが出てダメです。

```
interface IClappedItem {
  user_id: number;
  clapped_num: number;
}
interface IClappedItems {
 {[key:number]: IClappedItem[]}[]
};
```

自分なりに色々調べてみましたが、解決せず…。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

最初の「下記の様な」構造がうまく表記できていないので、うまく行っていないような気がします。

目標としては、このような宣言ができるように`IClappedItems`を定義したいのだと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか?

```
const clapped_items: IClappedItems = {
    2: [
        {
            "user_id": 0,
            "clapped_num": 15
        },
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "clapped_num": 3
        },
    ],
    5: [
        {
            "user_id": 3,
            "clapped_num": 15
        },
        {
            "user_id": 2,
            "clapped_num": 3
        },
        {
            "user_id": 4,
            "clapped_num": 11
        },
    ]
};
```

だとすれば、`clapped_items`の一番外側の構造は配列ではなく、オブジェクトです。

- 外側の`[]`は要りません
- `{ }`を二重にする必要はありません

と言うわけで、このようにすればいいはずです。

```
interface IClappedItem {
  user_id: number;
  clapped_num: number;
}
interface IClappedItems {
 [key:number]: IClappedItem[]
};
```

---

もし、私の解釈が誤っていて、「配列を値に持つオブジェクト」ではなく、「配列の配列」(*２次元配列*)を定義したいのであれば、ご質問文がそれを正しく表すよう、修正してください。